# Efficiently creating UI elements from XML file (OpenGL / C# NET 6.0)

Tags: c#, xml, user-interface, game-development, opentk

I'm currently working on a small game framework, build on top of OpenTK. In this project there should also be a way to easily create UI elements by defining their layout in an XML file, like WPF and XAML but way less complex (no bindings planned etc).

Now I'm kind of stuck when it comes to efficiently creating these ui elements from the XML file. The concept is that there are few core elements like image, label and panes for layouting and the structure of all more complex elements are defined in XML and represented by a seperated class (that inherits from UIElement, the base class for all UIElements).

For example, this is how it could look like for a button:

Button.xml

```
<Button Layout="AlignLayout Stretch Stretch">
    <Image Name="image"></Image>
    <Image Name="hoverImage"></Image>
    <Image Name="pressedImage"></Image>
    <AlignPane HorizontalLayout="Center" VerticalLayout="Center">
        <Label Name="label"
               IgnoreInputEvents="true">
        </Label>
    </AlignPane>
</Button>
```

Button.cs

```
public class Button : UIElement
{
    protected Image image;
    protected Image hoverImage;
    protected Image pressedImage;
    protected Label label;

    public Button(UIElement? parent, Texture2D backgroundTexture,
        Texture2D hoverTexture, Texture2D pressedTexture,
        string text) : base(parent)
    {
        // Receive XML layout here probably? (from cache, not parsed)

        image.Texture = backgroundTexture;
        hoverImage.Texture = hoverTexture;
        pressedImage.Texture = pressedTexture;
        label.Text = text;

        // ...
    }
}
```

and the usage in code would simply be:

```
Button startButton = new Button(OverlayUICanvas, bgTex, hovTex, prsTex, "Start");
```

or use the  element in some other XML file.

The element attributes in xml set properties in the corresponding class (except "Name", which is expected to set the fields/properties in the root element to the instance of the created class)

Basically i got something like this working already except that it is super inefficient (probably because all the reflection going on including parametered constructor calls). While testing it took over 100ms to load something simple with just 8 total elements.

It wouldn't be too bad if i could somehow cache the loaded layout somehow and then just create a new instance, without all the reflection going on again (layout would be loaded at game start or something) but i really have no clue how i could archive this.

Creating new instance of these elements is pretty important: imagine the game needs to creates some elements at runtime from a list or something like that.

I didn't really found any good information on how to do this, not even sure if it is possible like that. If I undestood correctly, WPF solves this by generating some source code on compilation but it stated this only works for netstandard2.0 and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around if this would even help me solve this problem.

If you want to take a look at the current source yourself for some reason:

https://github.com/BlakkM9/VengineX/tree/master/VengineX/UI

but please keep in mind - this project is WIP, in a very very early state and nothing professional, really.

I'm graceful for any tips and hints that might lead me in the right direction!

Comment: It would be easier to use a DataTable(s) instead of classes for the properties where you do not need to use reflection.  You can read/write xml from a datatable in one instruction.

Comment: @jdweng thatnks, i'll check that out!

Comment: @jdweng OK, if i understood correctly: my UIElement base class would then just have a single Property called "Properties" of type data table, right? But would that mean these properties can only have build-in types (which is fine for most of them) but one very important property is Layout which is a class that will control all the childs position and dimensions (derived from this [class](https://github.com/BlakkM9/VengineX/blob/master/VengineX/UI/Layouts/Layout.cs)).

Comment: The table(s) columns would be the properties in the class.  You can have more than one table and you can put the tables into a DataSet and serialize (writexml method)he DataSet so you have only one xml file.

Comment: @jdweng what i ended up doing now was digging trough all the source generation stuff and finally got it working! thanks anyways! check out my [last commit](https://github.com/BlakkM9/VengineX/commit/bc3149f519b584c9ab5d086c7b2fb4f9b7abb0c8) if interested